# Retrieving only rows for which a join has a dependancy

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am creating a testing system where users are allowed to re-test until they have passed.  I would like to get a list, for a given UserID, of tests which are assigned to them which they have scored less than passing (100% for this example) on.

I have the following tables:

> (Everything here has been adapted for simplicity, but it should all be valid still)

```
Users
(Generic "users" table with UserID and Name, etc...)

Tests
+--------+----------+------------------+
| TestID | TestName | OtherTestColumns |
+--------+----------+------------------+
|      1 |   Test 1 |         Blah.... |
|      2 |   Test 2 |         Blah.... |
|      3 |   Test 3 |         Blah.... |
|      4 |   Test 4 |         Blah.... |
+--------+----------+------------------+

Users_Have_Tests
  Users are assigned tests they must take with this table
+--------+--------+
| UserID | TestID |
+--------+--------+
|      1 |      1 |
|      1 |      2 |
|      1 |      3 |
|      2 |      1 |
|      2 |      2 |
|      2 |      3 |
+--------+--------+

TestResults
+--------+--------+------------+
| TestID | UserID | Percentage |
+--------+--------+------------+
|      1 |      1 |         75 |
|      1 |      1 |        100 |
|      2 |      1 |         80 |
|      2 |      1 |        100 |
|      1 |      2 |        100 |
|      2 |      2 |         75 |
+--------+--------+------------+
```

The following query works for me to figure out ALL tests which are assigned to a user, but I want to remove tests they have passed from this list

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TestID,
    TestName
FROM
    `Users` AS u
RIGHT JOIN
    `Users_have_Tests` AS ut
    ON
        u.UserID = ut.UserID
LEFT JOIN
    `Tests` AS t
    ON
        ut.TestID = t.TestID
WHERE UserID = 1
```

I feel like I need a subquery here.  I came up with the following query to find the max scores for each test a user has taken, but I'm not quite sure how to tie them together.  (Subqueries are very new to me and I'm still trying to understand them.)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TestID,
    MAX(Percentage)
FROM
    `TestResults`
WHERE UserID = 1
GROUP BY TestID
```

The results I am looking for are:

```
UserID = 1
+--------+----------+
| TestID | TestName |
+--------+----------+
|      3 |   Test 3 |
+--------+----------+

UserID = 2
+--------+----------+
| TestID | TestName |
+--------+----------+
|      2 |   Test 2 |
|      3 |   Test 3 |
+--------+----------+
```

I have tried several manners of joins and conditions, but I can't quite wrap my head around what exactly I need here.  Google and StackOverflow have failed me; Likely because I'm lacking the knowledge of what to search for.

**EDIT**
The following is what worked for me:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.TestID, t.TestName
    FROM 'Users' AS u
    RIGHT JOIN 'Users_have_Tests' AS ut
        ON u.UserID = ut.UserID
    LEFT JOIN 'Tests' AS t
        ON ut.TestID = t.TestID
    WHERE t.TestID NOT IN (
        SELECT tr.TestID
            FROM TestResults AS tr
            WHERE tr.Percentage >= 100
            AND tr.UserID = 2
        )
    AND u.UserID = 2
```

Comment: why not also just use `WHERE Percentage <> 100`

Comment: then you could also do a `GROUP BY UserID`

Comment: @Calum Using a WHERE Percentage < 100 doesn't work, since if a user has tried the test a couple times before passing this will still equate TRUE.  Grouping by UserID will only ever return a single row since I already have a WHERE UserID = $uid

Comment: think i understand what you are after, I have posted an answer below, if you do want just a specific users results then just remove the `GROUP BY` statement and add your `UserID = 1` statement into the `WHERE` clause using an `AND`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you are after now, give this a go:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        TestID,
        TestName
    FROM
        `Users` AS u
    RIGHT JOIN
        `Users_have_Tests` AS ut
        ON
            u.UserID = ut.UserID
    LEFT JOIN
        `Tests` AS t
        ON
            ut.TestID = t.TestID
    WHERE TestID NOT IN (SELECT TestID
                         FROM TestResults
                         Where Percentage = 100)
    GROUP BY UserID
```

Comment: Ah-ha!  Very useful!  I had to tweak it a *bit*, but you got me down the right path!  Thanks!
Here is what I used:
`SELECT DISTINCT
        t.TestID,
        t.TestName
    FROM
        'Users' AS u
    RIGHT JOIN
        'Users_have_Tests' AS ut
        ON
            u.UserID = ut.UserID
    LEFT JOIN
        'Tests' AS t
        ON
            ut.TestID = t.TestID
    WHERE t.TestID NOT IN (SELECT tr.TestID
                         FROM TestResults AS tr
                         WHERE tr.Percentage >= 100
                         AND tr.UserID = 2)
    AND u.UserID = 2`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following?

Edit I noticed you want to see the highest score, so I created a subquery

Edit I forgot a grouping.

Also, Test needs to be joined on both the TestID and UserID.

```
        SELECT
            TestID,
            TestName,
            HighestScore
        FROM
            `Users` AS u
        RIGHT JOIN
            `Users_have_Tests` AS ut
            ON
                u.UserID = ut.UserID
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT TestID, UserID, MAX(Percentage) AS HighestScore
            FROM `Tests`
            GROUP BY TestID, UserID         
        )AS t
            ON
                ut.TestID = t.TestID
            AND ut.UserID = t.UserID
        WHERE HighestScore < 100
        GROUP BY TestID, TestName, HighestScore
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but why not just run the following query and process the results?

```
    SELECT ut.UserId, ut.TestId, t.TestName
    FROM `Users_Have_Tests` ut INNER JOIN `TestResults` r ON ut.TestId = r.TestId
      INNER JOIN `Tests` t ON t.TestId = r.TestId
    WHERE r.Percentage < 100
    ORDER BY ut.UserId, ut.TestId;
```

If you plan on executing this for a single user just add a WHERE clause entry to filter against a single UserId value.

Comment: That could work if there is no other solution, although it would require quite a bit of coding on the backend.  I would have to create an array of Tests and loop through it for each SQL row to see if I needed to add it to the array or not.  Not the most elegant of solutions and certainly not the fastest.

If I'm going to just process the result I would rather return the highest score per test for the user and filter in my program based on that.

Comment: maybe I'm not understanding what you're after...  You want a distinct list of Users?  Above you state that you want a list of all tests that are not passed.  That could result in multiple rows for each user.  Also, you need a user's max score on _any_ test or max score _per_ test?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - I'm looking for a list of all tests assigned to a specific user which the user has not yet passed.  (So I can present a list to the user of tests they must still complete)  The max score query I have returns the max score _per_ test.

Answer (score 0):

Tryin the having clause

after calling

MAX(Percentage) AS HighestScore

after the group by say

HAVING Highest_Score < 100

then replace 100 with whatever the minimum passing score is.. only tests without a maximum entry above passing will be returned.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html